# Would 'Detect Magic' reveal spell scrolls?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items

On the [compendium of Roll20](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Spell%20Scroll#content) spell scrolls are listed under *Items*. **So I wondered whether a spell scroll is actually considered to be a Magic Item**, in case a PC casts *Detect Magic* to reveal it.

I'm asking this to find out whether my wizard could, while exploring, concentrate on *Detect Magic* to search for hidden spell scrolls.

Comment: I think the premise of this question is a bit weird, because Roll20's Items list contains magic items as well. Just looking down the list, I see things like Amulet of Health and +X weapons...

Comment: @Icyfire, if you scroll down in the link of the Q, you'll see the stat block state *Category: Items* rather than *Magic Item*. That's what caused my confusion.

Comment: That's true of all of the magic items on Roll20's list, though.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Yes.

In DMG p.139 *Scrolls* are listed under **Magic Item Categories**:

> The most prevalent type of scroll is the *spell scroll* (...). A scroll is a consumable magic item.

PHB p.231 mentions about *Detect Magic*:

> For the duration [of 10 minutes], **you sense the presence of magic within 30 feet** of you. If you sense magic in this way, you can use your action to see a faint aura around any visible creature or object in the area that bears magic, and you learn its school of magic, if any.
>
> The spell can penetrate most barriers, but it is blocked by 1 foot of stone, 1 inch of common metal, a thin sheet of lead, or 3 feet of wood or dirt.

So:
**Yes, using this spell enables you to sense spell scrolls in the vicinity.**

It's unclear to me why that [Roll20 compendium](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Items:Spell%20Scroll#content) would contradict the information in the DMG. *EDIT: See comments by [Icyfire](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/32262/icyfire) in the question for a clarification.*

Comment: Roll20 has a license to use the rules on their site, however, they are not a WotC source and so mistakes are going to be present that are not in official materials potentially.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie Given that detect magic penetrates many types of barriers, the scroll would have to be made from a thin sheet of lead in order to be blocked, even if it's just the writing that is magical. "The spell can penetrate barriers, but 1 foot of stone, 1 inch of common metal, a thin sheet of lead, or 3 feet of wood or dirt blocks it."

Comment: Even if the wizard sensed the magic scroll, all they would know is that they were in 30 get off something magical. Until they actually had a visual on it they would have to look for it.