# Can Wish give me a contingent spell?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, wish

*Wish* allows the user to "Duplicate any wizard or sorcerer spell of 8th level or lower, provided the spell is not of a school prohibited to you". Is this enough to give myself, say, contingent True Seeing? I'm trying to give this benefit to a caster who hypothetically knows neither *Contingency* nor *True Seeing* .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can, and there is no reason whatsoever to think that *wish* would be required to supply the companion spell—that could just be cast regularly as you cast *wish*-as-*contingency*. And if you want to cast *wish*-as-*true seeing* as the companion spell, there is also no reason that should fail.

Basically, it works because everything involved says it works, and nothing says it doesn’t. You need two castings of *wish*, but you can cast *wish* twice so that’s not a problem.

Trying to get the final *contingent true seeing* result from a single casting of *wish*, though, that would be a “greater effect.”

Comment: OK Here I agree

Answer (score 0):

## YES but...

Since *Wish* only duplicates effects of existing spells, and that *Contingency* would produce no effects by itself it would fall in the Greater effects category if you don't cast the companion spell yourself or have another Wish mimic the companion spell (Thanks @KRyan)

*Wish* states:

> (...)You may try to use a wish to produce greater effects than these, but doing so is dangerous. (The wish may pervert your intent into a literal but undesirable fulfillment or only a partial fulfillment.)(...)

### Sidenotes

- If you want to go safe *Use Magic Device* might be your best option,
  there's always the spell *Divine Insight* (up to +15 on a single
  skill check) that could help you with harder UMD rolls. or *Greater
  heroism* (+4) if you want to make it cheap depending on your class.
- If you're a wizard with prohibited schools, some prestige classes
  might help you but if the spell is just hard to get, you could craft a scroll with *limited wish* (if the DM agrees) or even *Wish* to craft a scroll of a rare spell so you can write it in your spellbook! see [My answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/158756/51979) and [Quadratic Wizard's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/158774/51979) to the question:[Can you craft magic items using Wish instead of the required spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/158734/can-you-craft-magic-items-using-wish-instead-of-the-required-spell)
   for more info on the mentionned method.
- If you're a sorcerer perhaps *Knowstones* are    accessible.
- Clerics also have access to domains with those spells but you would
  cast *Miracle* instead if you were one without the right domains. Last suggestion, perhaps
  *Miracle* (via an ally maybe?) with the very powerful request option could give it to you, might not be possible unless you're the one to
  cast it, if you use UMD to do so... might as well go with
  *contingency* scroll via UMD and *True seeing* scroll via UMD...